# WPF Button Focus error

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button

I have modified my wpf button but the problem is when i hit the tab the next button got a rectangle over it and my effect got overrides

any solution ??

Comment: help us to help you and show some code or explain well what and how you have modified, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the FocusVisualStyle to null for the control that you don't want focus rectangle to appear on.

```
<MyControl FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
```